# java 8 collectors for streams with generics

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

I have a class with long field (primitive type):

```
class Transfer {
       private long id;
       //gets sets
}
```

I want to get a `List<Long>` from `Collection<Transfer>` which would contain all ids from `Collection<Transfer>` e.g.

```
Collection<Transfer> transfers = ..;
List<Long> ids = (List<Long>) transfers.stream().map(f -> f.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The thing which confuses me is this ugly cast:

```
(List<Long>) transfers.stream()
```

Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: You don't need to cast it. The type of the list will be inferred without additional info. Also you could use a method reference in the map method to make the code clearer: `.map(Tranfer::getId)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `getId()` method return type is `long` or `Long`, this cast is absolutely unnecessary. You can write

```
List<Long> ids = transfers.stream().map(f -> f.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```